# iOS Textfields to variables: Thread 1 SIGABRT crash

Tags: ios, swift, crash, textfield

I am trying to input information in a textfield and then store the information that is typed out as a variable, to be used in a string. For some reason it crashes whenever I click on the next textfield after the first, or the third after the second. Here is what I have.

```
var name: String?
@IBAction func nameField(name: UITextField) {

    let name = name.text

}

var contact: String?
@IBAction func contactField(contact: UITextField) {

    let contact = contact.text

}


var other: String = "nothing"
@IBAction func otherField(other: UITextField) {

    if other == nil {

    }else{
        let other = other.text!
    }

}
```

Comment: You have too many variables with the same name. For example, in the `nameField` function, the parameter `name` will hide the property `name`. And then the local variable `name` hides the parameter `name`.

Comment: Based on [your newer question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51051535/cannot-get-string-variables-from-textfield-to-pass-into-mail-button-function) it seems you fixed this problem. You should delete this question.