# Cannot get string variables from textfield to pass into mail button function

Tags: ios, swift, string, button, textfield

I have an app that allows the user to input their contact information and it sends the mail to my email address with the information they put into the textfields. Everything seems to work and I can send the mail with the desired text, however I can't seem to input the information from the textfield. Please help! Im kind of new to this :)

```
var name: String?
@IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!

var contact: String?
@IBOutlet weak var contactField: UITextField!

var other: String = "nothing"
@IBOutlet weak var otherField: UITextField!


@IBAction func sendEmail(_ sender: Any) {

    let name = nameField.text

    let contact = contactField.text

    if other == nil {

    }else{
        let other = otherField.text!
    }
```

When I click the button, it pulls up the mail app with information in the body. Here is the code:

```
func configureMailController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["email@gmail.com"])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("Contact information")
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Another Friend! \nMy name or business is: \(name) \nMy contact information is: \(contact) \nMy additional information includes: \(other)", isHTML: false)

    return mailComposerVC
}
```

Here is the output in the body of the mail app (even when I write things in the textfield):

"Another Friend!

My name or business is: nil

My contact information is: nil

My additional information includes: nothing"

EDIT:

Ive change my `sendMail` function to simply contain the outlet names:

```
func configureMailController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["danielgannage@gmail.com"])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("Staples Day")
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Another Friend! \nMy name or business is: \(nameField.text) \nMy contact information is: \(contactField.text) \nMy additional information includes: \(otherField.text)", isHTML: false)

    return mailComposerVC
}
```

And now my output has textfield info:

"Another Friend!

My name or business is: Optional("whatever I put in the textfield")

My contact information is: Optional("whatever I put in the textfield")

My additional information includes: Optional("whatever I put in the textfield")"

But how do I get rid of the: `Optional("")` surrounding my string?

Comment: You never set the `name`, `contact`, and `other` properties. This is the same problem in the code in [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51051241/ios-textfields-to-variables-thread-1-sigabrt-crash).

Comment: Im not sure what do you mean. isn't the property of those variables set in the `sendEmail` func?

Comment: No, you set local variables that happen to have the same name as your properties.

Comment: So my properties are the outlets from the textfield? How would I set properties?

Comment: Change `let name = nameField.text` to `name = nameField.text`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Learning how to handle optional variables is an essential part of learning Swift. There are several methods to do what you are trying to do. If you are okay if some of these fields being unanswered, you could use a nil coalescing operator to set a default value. For example:

```
let name = nameField.text ?? "unknown"
```

Alternately, if it is no good without an answer, you could guard against that case:

```
guard let contact = contactField.text else { 
    // display missing info error 
    return
}
```

This would end the function, and not call the email client.

Comment: thank you! does the "unknown" have to be unknown or can it be a blank: "" or any other word in quotes. wondering what the quotes mean? does it mean if theres nil in the textfield then use this string instead?

Comment: It can be any string you choose. It is just a default value to be used if the .text value is nil. The nil coalescing operator (the ??) essentially evaluates the expression before and if it evaluates to nil, then uses the second value. The only reason for the quotes is that this is a string value. If you had a variable named someInt with type Int? (optional integer), you could have `value = someInt ?? 0` and zero would be the default.

Answer (score -1):

just add ! at the end like
let contact = contactField.text!

Comment: why do we need ! at the ends?

Comment: Becaus it's an optional. You really should **NOT** be going with this answer. Even though this works, it's prone to crashes if the value is nil since you're force-unwrapping an optional. Instead, see GntlmnBndt's answer.

Comment: –1 because you're suggesting very bad practice. You should learn more about optionals and use the ways suggested in GntlmnBndt's answer. @AlibEzbar

Comment: let value = edTest.text // for empty always return ""
        
edTest.text = nil // ok, lets try to do it nil
        
print("value: +\(value!)+") // magic. no crash. just ++ in result